# hello world with vba on mac with excel 2011

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Can someone help me with a hello world in vba with excel 2011 for the mac.

Do I need visual studio?

Thanks

Comment: http://excelsemipro.com/2010/11/excel-2011-for-mac-installation-preferences-and-vba/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An OK message

```
Sub  Newworld()
    MsgBox("Hello World")
End Sub
```